Identify this movie: 90's - I believe
I saw this movie as a child and can only recall bits of it, but I had no luck searching for it, this is what I remember.
A white family of aliens come to earth (mother, father, adult daughter). The parents are violent and there are three separate scenes where they first kill one man, then a gang of 2 men and finally a gang of three men.
The daughter falls in love with a black man from Earth and they convince the parents to go to prison under the guise they can kill and be violent in there.
There is one other scene I vaguely remember where the daughter is proving to her new lover she is indeed an alien and pulls up the skin on her arm revealing a murky green under-layer.

This could be Alien Avengers (AKA Welcome To  Planet Earth) with George Wendt from 1997 about an alien family (dad, mom & attractive daughter) who come to earth, reside in a bad neighborhood and proceed to eat the 'lowlife'. The daughter falls in love and the parents are sent to prison in the end according to this recap.
